# Send Images to devices via Airplay

Tags: ios, airplay

I have an app that supports Airplay and It can send audio and video content to Airplay without any problem.

I also have slideshow support in my app and I am trying to find how to send the photo information to the airplay selected device. That way when the user looks through the photo, the airplay image also changes.   I am looking to implement this in iOS5.1.

I know this is possible using the native photo app.

Is this accomplished using Mirroring?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.